# Emgu.CV GpuSURFDetector against n-images?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I'm trying to extend the example below to allow for matching against more than one reference image. Does anyone know how to do this?

I'm not sure how to concat multiple sets of gpuModelDescriptors into something that the detector can use. Surely there must be a way to compare an image against an entire set of reference images and not one at a time?

The goal is to load a big set of reference images to the GPU, and then compare observed images against the references looking for a (close) match with adjustable tolerance/precision. Thanks in advance for any light you can shed on this. I've been struggling with it for many months.

Example: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/SURF_feature_detector_in_CSharp

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is NO out-of-the-box solution for your task on emgucv.

> into something that the detector can use

The role of detector is only to detect the key points.

The example takes 2 image, detects key points, produce descriptors for each and compares them by matching.
You need to modify the process of gathering and managing descriptors (for all the images you want to use as reference) and then apply the matching of each of your observed images. 
Note that you should store the info so that you can say which image and which keypoint each descriptor corresponds to.
So the task is not so trivial as it may seems at first glance.